# Could not install typings files... in VS Code, with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. I have VS Code installed on Windows, but otherwise use Bash exclusively for my JavaScript development workflow.

I have `node` and `npm` installed on Bash (via `apt-get`), however, I do not have `node` and `npm` also on Windows to avoid duplication. In my VS Code settings, I have configured the integrated shell to use Bash:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe"
```

The integrated shell works fine, and `node` and `npm` are both accessible. However, when I launch VS Code on my project, I get the warning:

```
Could not install typings files for JavaScript langauge features. Please ensure that NPM is installed or configure 'typescript.npm' in your user settings
```

I have tried both the following settings, neither of which work:

```
"typescript.npm": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe"
"typescript.npm": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe -c \"npm\""
```

Is it possible to get VS Code to install typings files via the `npm` that is installed on Bash?

Comment: You can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450218/how-do-i-use-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-wsl-for-my-vs-code-terminal Check the **Node.js & NPM** section

Comment: Guess you have Git installed on your Windows machine as well.  You can try this to see if it will work: "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\bin\\bash.exe".  But make sure bash.exe is located in that Git installation path.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `“externalTerminal.windowsExec”: “bash”` in your settings file to set it as the terminal executable and then restart VS Code