# How to configure VS Code (windows) to use Ubuntu App as terminal

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu App on Windows 10 and I would like to use it as a terminal in VS Code. I see VS Code automatically detecting options like Git Bash, PowerShell, Cmd.exe and gives options to use them as terminal. But I would like to use Ubuntu. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

For specifically using Ubuntu distro you just have to type a simple command to change the default distro used by wsl to ubuntu.
Type `wslconfig /setdefault Ubuntu` in cmd thats it.

Then in my pc vscode gave me option to choose which terminal i wanted to use so i selected wsl bash so it edited the user settings `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe"`in Preferences->settings . The above code overrides the default setting.

Your pc may have a different path so refer to [stackoverflow link to configure vscode for wsl as terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450218/how-do-i-use-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-wsl-for-my-vs-code-terminal)

you can also refer to the microsoft link for wsl configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

you can refer to [similar question as yours for ubuntu and multiple distros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473965/ubuntu-on-windows-as-vs-code-terminal-executable-path)

Answer (score 1):

I have configured VS code as follows, so I can use it as "integrated Terminal"

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Ubuntu (WSL)": {
        "path": "wsl.exe",
        "args": ["-d", "ubuntu"]
    }
},
...
```

[image: Integrated Terminal WSL]