# Ubuntu on Windows as VS Code terminal - executable path

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44450218/2715716) but it details the approach for WSL, in newer versions of Windows, the Linux distributions are not beta anymore and they are provided through the MS app store.

Where do I find the path to Ubuntu on Windows executable? (Not WSL.) I tried right-clicking on the icon to find Properties, but it is not there, it seems to be some special kind of a shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple distros installed, you can read this how to launch one individually.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/wsl-config

However if you only have 1 installed, it will pick that one by default

> There are three ways to launch and run WSL:
>
> wsl.exe or bash.exe
>   wsl -c [command] or bash -c [command]
>   [distro] ie ubuntu -- this is the same as launching the installed app from the Windows menu.
>
> In the first two cases, WSL must pick a distribution to run - a default distribution. If you don't explicitly set a default, it will be the first one installed.

So you can continue to simply use bash.exe

Answer (score 0):

1. Open VSCode Settings ***`Ctrl + ,`*** or ***`File > Prefrences > Settings`***
2. User Settings will open up. Add the following in that file:

   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"
3. Save and close the user settings file.
4. Enjoy bash in VSCode!