# "Permission Denied" trying to run Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-store-apps, file-permissions, git-bash

Seems as though an update on Windows 10 overnight broke Python. Just trying to run `python --version` returned a "Permission Denied" error.  None of the three updates; KB4507453, KB4506991, or KB4509096 look like they'd be the culprit but the timing of the issue is suspicious. Rather than messing with rolling back, I'm hoping there's a simpler fix that I'm missing.

The permissions on python are "-rwxr-xr-x" and I haven't changed anything besides letting the Windows update reboot machine after installing last night's patches.

According to the System Information, I'm running 10.0.18362

Should also note that this is happening whether I (try) to execute Python from git-bash using "run as administrator" or not, and if I try using PowerShell, it just opens the Windows store as if the app isn't installed so I'm thinking it can't see the contents of my `/c/Users/david/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/` folder for some reason.

I've also tried to reinstall Python 3.7.4, but that didn't help either. Is there something else I should be looking at?

Comment: Probably worth checking the Microsoft website. I read somewhere, sorry can't remember where, that other people were having problems with this update - blank screen I think. Anyway, waiting until they fix it in a day or two might turn out to be the answer.

Comment: BTW, "permissions on python are '-rwxr-xr-x'" is probably meaningless in Windows. That's something fake reported by a Unix-like environment such as MSYS2 or git-bash.

Comment: Nope. This is the Python package from python.org. Same on that's been working for years without any issue and just started acting up with the latest Windows patch.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/1576801/93082 solution #1 `mklink \Python39\python3.exe \Python39\python.exe`

Answer (score 342, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this was caused by a conflict with the version of Python 3.7 that was recently added into the Windows Store. It looks like this added two "stubs" called python.exe and python3.exe into the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` folder, and in my case, this was inserted **before** my existing Python executable's entry in the `PATH`.

Moving this entry below the correct Python folder (partially) corrected the issue.

The second part of correcting it is to type `manage app execution aliases` into the Windows search prompt and disable the store versions of Python altogether.

[image: manage app execution aliases]

It's possible that you'll only need to do the second part, but on my system I made both changes and everything is back to normal now.

Comment: I have in my local user's path variable two references to this same folder, one with a literal path, the other with a relative path: `C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` is the 4th entry, and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` is the last entry in the list. -- On the other hand, my *system* path variable contains no reference to the WindowsApps folder at all. Additionally, neither one of these contains a reference to any other Python paths.

Comment: (Microsoft employee and CPython core developer here) You definitely only need to do the second part. There have been a couple of bugs related to upgrading apps resetting aliases which will be fixed in the next stable update, so it should be a one-time fix by then. While you're getting Insiders updates you may need to do it a couple more times.

Comment: Also, the "Access Denied" issue is a Git Bash bug (or whoever maintains their Bash port... I'm not sure myself whose it is). And launching the Store is a new feature to help people install Python - if you've added it to PATH using the regular installer it should take precedence over the new redirector, but if not you've discovered above how to disable it.

Comment: (To clarify my own comment - "if you've added it [Python, not the Store launcher] to PATH using the regular installer...")

Comment: I just had to to the second part to fix this problem for me.

Comment: For me I had to also add python to my path (C:\Users\YourUsernameHere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37) for git bash to find python

Comment: I never did anything with the winsows store regarding Python. Python is also not listet in 'App execution aliases'.

Comment: Adding it to my my path and moving it to the top was my solution, just like Neils did.  The fact that I can't just rename the stub for the windows store stub is pretty annoying.

Comment: doing just the second part crashes git bash on startup with a "There are no available terminal" error. this kind of insanity makes dual-booting and dealing with windows 10's chronic inability to share a system nicely look inviting

Comment: Just in case it helps.. I got this to work very simply by doing alias python='winpty python.exe' on the command line in git bash... On Windows 10 and after doing parts 1 and 2 above...

Comment: For me, the problem was that python was moved to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.8 instead of the default path. I removed all paths both from sublime and env variables, reinstalled, added new paths and now it works. The only problem is that it's a clean install and I have to reinstall all dependencies

Comment: What a complete waste of humanity's time. Whichever parties conspired to make this be the case need to seriously consider their career choices. Thanks for the fixes

Comment: Adding in to the path manually and disabling those aliased did it for me Python 3.9.4

Comment: upvoted for the discovery of "manage app execution aliases"

Comment: even Windows 11 still has this issue. Followed the 2nd part and it fixed my problem. thanks ~!

Answer (score 36):

## Research

All of the files in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` are placeholders that point to files that are actually located somewhere in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, which happens to be denied permissions completely.

It appears I was on the right track with my statement made in my duplicate of this problem:

> "Seems like they didn't really think about the distribution method screwing with permissions!"

Source: [Cannot install pylint in Git Bash on Windows (Windows Store)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447363/cannot-install-pylint-in-git-bash-on-windows-windows-store)

Permissions are screwed up royally because of the WindowsApps distribution method:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Interestingly it says that the "Users" group can read and execute files, as well as my specific user, but the Administrators group can only List folder contents for some hilariously unfathomable reason. And when trying to access the folder in File Explorer, it refuses to even show the folder contents, so there's something fishy about that as well.

Interestingly, even though executing `python` in CMD works just fine, the "WindowsApps" folder does not show up when listing the files in the directory it resides in, and attempting to navigate into the folder generates a "Permission denied" error:

[image]

Attempting to change the permissions requires changing the owner first, so I changed the owner to the Administrators group. After that, I attempted to change the permissions for the Administrators group to include Full control, but it was unable to change this, because "access was denied" (duh, Micro$ucks, that's what we're trying to change!).

[image]

This permission error happened for so many files that I used Alt+C to quickly click "Continue" on repeat messages, but this still took too long, so I canceled the process, resulting in this warning message popping up:

[image]

And now I am unable to set the TrustedInstaller user back as the owner of the WindowsApps folder, because it doesn't show up in the list of Users/Groups/Built-in security principles/Other objects. *

[image]

*Actually, according to [this tutorial](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-restore-the-trustedinstaller-ownership-in-windows-10/), you can swap the owner back to TrustedInstaller by typing `NT Service\TrustedInstaller` into the object name text box.

## Solution

There is no solution. Basically, we are completely screwed. Classy move, Microsoft.

Comment: (Microsoft employee and CPython core developer here) There's a bug right now I'm working on getting fixed in Windows where you can launch executables in this location but only if you have the global alias enabled (in Manage App Execution aliases). I'm trying to get it changed so that you only need to have installed the app for the current user.

Comment: We can read the permissions via this dialog because it's owned by a dllhost.exe instance (hosting the security shell extension, rshx32.dll) that's running with administrator access and thus has "list folder contents" access (i.e. execute; sync; and read data, attributes, and permissions). The entry for the users group is not for a normal access check. It's conditional on the existence of a WIN://SYSAPPID security attribute, i.e. any app. The subfolder for each app grants read access to users, but execute access is conditional on running via the app link that sets a custom access token.

Comment: @ErykSun That is the first informed answer I've ever seen about windows execution and permissions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually still dealing with the fallout from trying to change permissions on the folder. Certain WinApps stopped launching altogether, until I followed these directions: (https://superuser.com/questions/1288014/reset-default-acls-for-c-program-files-windowsapps) but now they give error messages on launching. I used an older Win10 USB image so it probably set the permissions incorrectly.

Comment: This just caught me out, thanks for the good explanation. We use git bash to run shell scripts to invoke an emscripten build, and as part of the standard emscripten scripts it tries to divine your python version via $(which python) ... which immediately blows up.

Comment: @MarkSimpson glad this thread helped. Not sure what I may have written. Be sure to thank the Microsoft employees that posted real answers in the comments here.

Comment: this bug still seems to be lurking over a year later... as far as i can tell getting GitBash, python and windows 10 to work together is still a dead end

Answer (score 27):

This appears to be a limitation in git-bash. The recommendation to use `winpty python.exe` worked for me. See [Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash) for additional information.

Comment: I definitely have this issue running python from bash but not from powershell - however I don't think the bug you linked is the issue. Much more likely to be this: https://github.com/msys2/Msys2-packages/issues/1943

Comment: the thing is, microsoft has no right to invent new operating system features, since those would not be standard, thats something only linux/posix can do. so msys2, kudos to them for putting up with all the msft they have, and im sure theyll figure this one out too, but its not their fault its msft

Answer (score 21):

This issue is far too common to still be persistent. And most answers and instructions fail to address it. Here's what to do on Windows 10:

1. Type `environment variables` in the start search bar, and open **Edit the System Environment Variables**.
2. Click **Environment Variables...**
3. In the System Variables section, locate the variable with the key `Path` and double click it.
4. Look for paths pointing to python files. Likely there are none. If there are, select and delete them.
5. Create a new variable set to the path to your python executable. Normally this is `C:\Users\[YOUR USERNAME HERE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`. Ensure this by checking via your File Explorer.

   **Note**: If you can't see `AppData`, it's because you've not [enabled viewing of hidden items](https://www.technipages.com/show-hidden-files-windows): click the View tab and tick the Hidden Items checkbox.
6. Create another variable pointing to the `Scripts` directory. Typically it is `C:\Users\[YOUR USERNAME HERE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Scripts`.
7. Restart your terminal and try typing `py`, `python`, `python3`, or `python.exe`.

Comment: What about users who installed Python via Anaconda? I did all every step, a system variable pointing to my python installation exists in system variables and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 20):

Simple answer: replace **python** with **PY** everything will work as expected

Comment: so that´s a new thing implemented in py 3.9.4?

Comment: Could anyone add more context on what is `PY` ?

Comment: worked for me, not sure whey

Answer (score 16):

Workaround: If you have installed python from exe follow below steps.

Step 1: Uninstall python

Step 2: Install python and check Python path check box as highlighted in below screentshot(yellow).

This solved me the problem.

[image]

Comment: I did this, after I installed Python - it was not installed initially, hence the error :)

Comment: Then you should have seen installation error.

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT WAY TO DO!! THANKS!!

Answer (score 9):

Adding the Local Python Path before the WindowsApps resolved the problem.

[image: Environment Variables > Path]

[image: Bash Python --Version]

Comment: this actually worked, this is like what the hell situation. lol :D

Answer (score 8):

For people coming to this question **wanting to use the Microsoft Store** version of Python, and after the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168165/3003133) "Manage app execution aliases" fix by [@Zooba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891/zooba) has likely happened, and are using [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) git-bash (also known as BASH through msys2 mintty), the solution is likely simply to remember to make the call with `winpty`.'

```
winpty python3
```

---

However, if the system has had other versions of Python, make sure those copies have been removed (e.g. those installed from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)) or are contained to their specific bundled application (e.g. OSGeo4W) (may require [re-ordering environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61969875/3003133)).

Why, if `winpty` is forgotten, is it a permission error? For the first time it runs, the Microsoft Store stubs are conflicting with the permissions available to msys. A lot of the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57447610/3003133) go into the details of what is going on and why it feels weird. The short answer, is that the stub is trying to be a convenience short-cut to the Microsoft Store. If you launch it with `winpty`, it can do that. After that first time, it continues to need `winpty` for both related and unrelated reasons to the Microsoft Store.

Comment: There are other answers suggesting `winpty`, but their reasoning is unrelated, wrong, or out-dated. I felt an updated summary for 2021 could be useful.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a solution with PowerShell, but I had the same problem except with MINGW64. I got around it by switching to Windows Subsystem for Linux (which I wanted to do anyways) as my terminal, just generally and in VSCode. This post describes it well:

[How to configure VS Code (windows) to use Ubuntu App as terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462714/how-to-configure-vs-code-windows-to-use-ubuntu-app-as-terminal)

In summary:

1) Install Ubuntu from the Windows App Store

2) Change the default bash from CMD -> wslconfig /setdefault Ubuntu

--- For VSCode

3) Restart VSCode

4) In VSCode change "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" to "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" (for further details see the post above)

Running smoothly now in VSCode and WSL (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows). Might be at least a temporary solution for you.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I tried `manage app execution aliases` and got an error that python3 is not a command so for that, I used `py` instead of `python3` and it worked

I don't know why this is happening but It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the way Windows **App Execution Aliases** work in Git-Bash.

It is a known issue in **MSYS2** [failing to access Windows reparse points with `IO_REPARSE_TAG_APPEXECLINK`](https://github.com/msys2/Msys2-packages/issues/1943)

*As a workaround*, you can alias to a function invocation that uses `cmd.exe` under the hood.

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file::

```sh
function python { cmd.exe /c "python $1 $2 $3";}
```

For python, I'd recommend just toggling off app execution aliases as in the accepted answer, but for libraries that are distributed exclusively through the windows store like `winget`, this is your best option.

### Further Reading

- [bash: Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3: Permission denied](https://github.com/gmacario/spaceappschallenge-2019/issues/6)
- [Permission Denied when running from bash](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/228)
- [winget does not run in WSL2 due to exec format error #234](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/234#issuecomment-647641718)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to modify your PATH and PYTHONPATH environmental variables to make sure that the folder containing the proper python binaries are searched befor the local WindowsApp folder.  You can access the environmental variables by opening up the control panel and searching for "env"

Answer (score 1):

I had this to Run /execute but was not working

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

after reading and trying some of the solutions above and did not worked , what worked for me was

```
python -m http.server 8080
```

Comment: huh, worked for me when running `-m venv`. Looks like I may have python3 installed in two locations causing this. I suspect one from the Windows store and one installed by vscode or something like that. 

```
$ which python
/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python
$ which python3
/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3 
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure `C:\Python39\` and `C:\Python39\Scripts\` are added to both system path variables and user path variables

Comment: This helped me to get python running, though python was installed in C:\Program Files\Python36\. Make sure this is added to the top (beginning) of your PATH, otherwise Windows may try to run the Windows Store versions of python instead of the version you installed. Also, I never got it working in git bash, but it will work in cmd or powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, but in addition to Python being blocked, all programs in the `Scripts` folder were too. The other answers about aliases, path and `winpty` didn't help.

I finally found that it was my antivirus (Avast) which decided overnight for some reason to just block all compiled python scripts for some reason.

The fix is fortunately easy: simply whitelist the whole Python directory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223306/avast-blocks-pip-and-pyinstaller) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of python folder in environmental variable and it will work

1.search environmental variable

2.look for system variable section and find variable named path in it

3.double click on path and add new path which directs towards python folder and that's it.

the python folder is usually in
C:\Users["user name"]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled the Python 3.9 Version in the Windows App and Features.
Instead I installed the latest version with everything and with adding environment variable.

This helped me directly after that.

Answer (score -1):

save you time :
use `wsl  and vscode remote extension` to properly work with python even with win10 
and dont't forget `virtualenv`!
useful https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score -1):

***In Windows 10***

- Open **Control Panel**
- Click System
- Click the **Advanced system settings** link
- Click **Environment Variables** button
- In the System Variables section find the **PATH** environment variable and select it
- Click Edit (If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New)
- In the Edit environment variable window specify the value of the PATH environment variable
- Click OK
- Close all remaining windows by clicking OK
- Reopen Command prompt window and run `python --version`

Answer (score -2):

May be you can try opening command prompt with Administrator privileges. (Run As Administrator). Works for me most of the time.

Comment: The python executable works in CMD even without Administrator privileges. The problem is that it doesn't work in Git Bash, which is an essential tool for programmers and is the default, and it works with every other distribution method for Python, which means it should [be made to] work here as well.