# Cannot install pylint in Git Bash on Windows (Windows Store)

Tags: python-3.x, installation, file-permissions, git-bash, pylint

I installed Python 3.7 via the Windows Store. I have selected this runtime environment in VScode, and VScode insists on nagging me about installing the pylint addon (or another linting addon). It attempts to run this command in a Git Bash terminal (MINGW64):

```
$ C:/Users/rjamd/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe -m pip install -U pylint --user
```

...which is denied permission to run:

```
bash: C:/Users/rjamd/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe:
Permission denied
```

Seems like they didn't really think about the distribution method screwing with permissions!

I should not be getting *any* permissions issues, because this is attempting to run in my local user directory, which I have full permissions on.

Full permissions are granted to:

- SYSTEM (group)
- rjamd (my user)
- Administrators (group)

Everything appears to be in order.

Update:

- Python will not run at all in the Git bash terminal, but it runs in CMD (without running CMD as admin).
- Git bash cannot find any other instances of Python using `which --all python`. It prints the same executable path twice in a row. I have 3 conda environments, and two different paths for the new Python environment ("AppData" and "Program Files"), all of which show up in VScode's environment selection menu.

Comment: What if you tried something akin to: `pip install --user package_name`.   Pip by default will want to install for all users, but if you define *--user* it will only install it for the current user.

Comment: It also results in "Permission denied"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Permission Denied" trying to run Python on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974927/permission-denied-trying-to-run-python-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution by disabling execution aliases of python in

Windows setting > `Manage app execution aliases`

**See Also**: [bash: ...Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3: Permission denied](https://github.com/gmacario/spaceappschallenge-2019/issues/6)

Answer (score 1):

(Microsoft employee and CPython core developer here).

This is most likely a bug in Git Bash. They are probably trying to read some information from the executable in a way that doesn't handle reparse points correctly (and may not be able to handle Windows symlinks either, in that case).

Launching the executable under `AppData` from anywhere else in Windows should be okay, though if you can't launch it with PowerShell or cmd.exe, please use the Windows Feedback tool to report a bug for the team.

Comment: Have you thought of creating an issue on their end? This will affect quite some devs once WinGet starts to spread. Most devs I know, use Bash on Windows...