# python (installed from anaconda) does not compile

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3, conda

I installed Anaconda3 using the installer found on their website for Windows. The installation completed successfully with me selecting all the default installation options. I can run the Anaconda Prompt and python runs fine there.

However, when I try using sublime text 3, python code does not build. I get an error message that says

```
Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 9009]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\__YALE\20spring\_PHYS261\HOMEWORK\pset8_3b.py"
[dir: D:\__YALE\20spring\_PHYS261\HOMEWORK]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;D:\_S\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;D:\_S\MATLAB\R2019b\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\joshc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\joshc\anaconda3;]
```

I've been through several threads and made sure to set the Anaconda3 folder in my environment path variables but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You were trying to compile your subline from your command prompt of windows. And you may not have entered the path python to the environmental variable.

Comment: @FAHADSIDDIQUI I was not compiling sublime from my command prompt windows, I was compiling my code in sublime text 3. Also, I made sure to enter the anaconda3 folder, which contains python.exe, to the environment variables

Comment: Windows 10 now includes helper stubs for python that direct you to the windows store, even if you have Python already installed. See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066455/python-was-not-found-but-can-be-installed/60066914#60066914

Comment: _made sure to set the Anaconda3 folder in my environment path variables_ Can you be more specific? That shouldn't be necessary, IIRC the installer should set everything up for you. For using Conda with Sublime, take a look at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/sublime/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865717/use-conda-environment-in-sublime-text-3.