# Trouble finding python in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I followed a udacity tutorial to download python and I'm having some trouble. I downloaded python and I can see that I have when I type in `python --version` in the terminal. It's version 3.8.2. When I type in `python3 --version`, I get: `/appData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3: Permission Denied`.

Why does `python --version` work but not `python 3 --version`? What permission is denied?

Comment: What did you write in the terminal? `python3 --version` or `python 3 --version` there's a significant difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Permission Denied" trying to run Python on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974927/permission-denied-trying-to-run-python-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this added two "stubs" called `python.exe` and `python3.exe` into the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` folder, it's inserted before existing Python executable's entry in the `PATH`.
Moving this entry below the correct Python folder (partially) corrected the issue.

Type `manage app execution aliases` into the Windows search prompt and disable the store versions of Python altogether.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I went to "manage app execution aliases" and disabled python.exe and python3.exe but python 3--version still won't work.