# Running Python on Git Bash

Tags: git, python-2.7

I'm running Git Bash on Windows 10.  It doesn't seem to allow me to run Python.

It returns the full path followed by ":Permission Denied"

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Permission Denied" trying to run Python on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974927/permission-denied-trying-to-run-python-on-windows-10)

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.  Python is now working in Git.