# Avast blocks pip and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, pyinstaller, virus

I'm making a Simple GUI Tkinter Program. I was going to compile my Program (with Pyinstaller) but Avast is blocking PIP. So I ignored it. When Compile was Finished.
I run the compiled .exe program and the program are saying:
failed to execute the script, Avast is blocking.
How to fix this error and What am the issue?

edit:now Avast is not blocking .exe(but blocking PIP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use avast as well. Avast sandboxes pipenv when installing a new package. Depending on what/if virtualenv your using.

You can whitelist/exclude python's install directory. For windows the default location is `%localappdata%\Programs\Python`. This is also where pip is installed globally as well as pyinstaller and other packages that are installed globally.

Be warned this will make it so avast no longer scans anything related to python in those directories. So if you're worried about getting a virus from a python package then you can whitelist/exclude the pip exe itself which is located specifically...

**32-bit Python 3.8**

`%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe`

**64-bit Python 3.8**

`%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe`

If you use a virtualenv whitelist/exclude those directories since those virtualenvs use a local copy of pip instead of the global one. That should fix avast messing with pip/virtualenv/pipenv

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention it according to the steps found in https://support.avast.com/en-gb/article/Antivirus-scan-exclusions/ you need to do the following to get pip whitelisted on Avast:

**STEPS**

Open Avast Antivirus and go to ☰ Menu ▸ Settings.

Select General ▸ Exceptions, then click Add exception.

Add an exception in one of the following ways:
Type the specific file/folder path or URL into the text box, then click Add exception.

Click Browse, tick the box next to a file or folder, For example in x64 system:  `HOME_DIRECTORY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe` (depending on your version of python), then click OK.

Click Add Exeption

Your specified files, folder, or website is added to the exceptions list.

NOTE: You can select or add multiple files so its good to select pip.exe and pip3.exe and pip39.exe, depending on what python version you are using and what pip files you have in the folder