# Why doesn't any python commands work in my command line?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I was normally using python3.7.3 on my system(Windows 10). A couple of days earlier I noticed that the command prompt won't run any of my python programs. It did nothing, no response. I thought there is a problem displaying the output stream so I ran an infinite loop(and was expecting to terminate the process, ctrl^c) but again no response. Even `python --version` command won't work. I uninstalled python3.7.3, downloaded the latest python3.8.5, and again the same problem. [image from my cmd line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFN74.png)

please help me out. I use sublime text so I prefer running my codes through cmd.

Update: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNRgX.png) is another snap of my command line after running commands in one answer and comments.

Also, I think the problem lies within the PATH setting but PATHs are already added.
[image to enviornment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLElG.png), [image to system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhuRV.png)

Comment: What does `where python` give you?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974927/permission-denied-trying-to-run-python-on-windows-10 will offer some insight.

Comment: I suspect from your description that you have created an empty file called `python.cmd` or (less likely) `python.bat` that is in a folder that comes earlier in the path than your Python installation folder. It's easier to do that accidentally than you might imagine. Search your entire system for `python.*` and see what it turns up.

Comment: ```where python``` gives the exact location of my python.exe file.

Comment: And it also includes the windows store stub python executable.  You'll need to remove it following the directions on the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you failed to add python to your path in the installer.

[Image displaying adding python to your path in the installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhzQ.png)

You also may have forgotten to disable the path limit in the final set up screen.

[Image displaying increase path limit in the installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhzqk.png)

If you navigate to `C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32` then run `python --version` do you get any output?

Comment: Yes, ```python --version``` works in ```C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32```. ```python 3.8.5``` is the output I get.

Comment: I remember I checked 'add python3.8 to PATH'. But I didn't disable the path limit in the final set up screen. I thought it is better to leave it that way, could this be causing the issue?

Comment: add the folder containing python (`C:\Users\chira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32`) to the path [relevant guide](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)