# Gcloud commands on Windows (using git bash) are logging ERROR: WindowsApps/python3: permission denied

Tags: python, bash, powershell, gcloud, git-bash

All command work fine when I run it on Windows `PowerShell`.

At first I was not able to run any `gcloud` command from within a `.sh` script file or from a Git Bash terminal.

It seems that `git bash` wasn't able to find the bundled `Python` installation that comes with `gcloud` SDK.

So I've installed Python for Windows as well.

Now I'm able to run it both from `PowerShell`, `.sh file` and `Git bash`.

From `PowerShell`, I get a clean log like this:

[image]

But from I run it from an `.sh` script file or from a `Git bash` window. This gets logged:

[image]

It seems to be working fine, but there is this `Permission Denied` error from `WindowsApps/python3`.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 11):

Just found the answer on this other question: ["Permission Denied" trying to run Python on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974927/permission-denied-trying-to-run-python-on-windows-10)

I had to do this to fix it:

[image]

Comment: This solves it. But why and how did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

The fix which worked for me was to set my Python executable to a separate manual Python installation. This is done by setting CLOUDSDK_PYTHON variable (can also put in your bash profile to not have to set it each time):

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON='/c/Users/ALee/anaconda3/python.exe'`

(I used Anaconda, which also meant adding `/c/Users/ALee/anaconda3/Library/bin` to my PATH for the DLLs)

I couldn't get the bundled Python installation with gcloud SDK to work even after installing it for all users, having Windows admin permissions, and running git bash with admin.