# Python file is not reading contents of a text file

Tags: python

My Python file, which is just a very small file, will not read the contents of a .txt file in the same folder as the python file. The (very simple) code is below:

```
file = open("contents.txt", "r")

print(file.read())

file.close()
```

Even this will not work! The contents.txt file contains:

```
random data that the python file should read
```

Can anyone help?

P.S. No errors are produced, and the command prompt app just moves on.

Comment: What do you mean by "this will not work?"  Do you see any errors?  What do you get printed to the screen?  How are you running the Python code?  Maybe Python doesn't have permissions to access the file.

Comment: "Even this will not work" - what do you mean ? Are there errors ? Does i print nothing ? Please add details to your post.

Comment: How do you run the Python script?

Comment: @RocketHazmat i duplicated your comment without knowing ....

Comment: after i put the 'python filename.py' in the command line, it will do nothing. No errors are produced, and it just does absolutely nothing. I have no better words to describe nothing.

Comment: @Programmer that's fine :-)  We all want to help here :-D

Comment: Are you with your cmd in the directory where you textfile is? Avoid using `file` as a variable. Is this all your code or you wrapped it into the function?

Comment: @JohnDoe could you post a screenshot of your screen directly after running the program ?

Comment: Do you by chance have the [Python app store stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168165/2378643) installed?  They can act like this when passed command lines.

Comment: Oh, and I am using Windows 10, Python 3.9.1, and I run the script in the command prompt app. Before, it would work perfectly

Comment: @JohnDoe Try wrapping this code in a `try`/`except` block.  Like `try: open(...) except Exception as e: print(e)`.

Comment: add `print("Hello !")` to the top of your script, and see if that gets printed.

Comment: Keep some print statements and check whether they're working or not

Comment: ok, i will do that, and i will screenshot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, it works. The file was located in a different folder, and once i brought it to the folder with the python file, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

first method:- you can simply write folder name before the file name.

second method:-   use the below code:-

```
with open("FolderName/fileName", "r") as f:

  a = f.read()

  print(a)
```