# winpty python.exe whenever you enter python

Tags: python, git-bash, anaconda3

I am trying to alias for Python in my `~/.bashrc` file. I am entering this command to tell Git Bash where to find the Python executable file:

```bash
python --version winpty
```

...from within my [Git Bash] and unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
MINGW64 ~
$ python --version
winpty: error: cannot start '"C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.4.3161.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe/AppInstallerPythonRedirector.exe" --version': Access is denied. (error 0x5)
```

How should I run python from the [Git Bash] properly?

Thank you.

Comment: You should change App Installers of python.exe and python3.exe as *off* from Settings/Apps/App Execution Aliases. I faced same error and it resolved. You can also check the link for detailed explanation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168165/15658588
Thanks to @notanumber

Comment: I saw this error too. Try following my instructions here: [Python doesn't work in Git Bash (it just hangs or freezes forever); and getting Linux hash-bangs to work in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76918262/4561887)

Answer (score 3):

Search for "App execution aliases" in Windows and make sure Appl Installer for python.exe is turned off.

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).