# Use non-default terminal in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to open a non-default terminal within VS Code in Windows? For example, my default is WSL bash, but how would I open a Windows cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I couldn't call cmd from WSL bash, but I just needed to call it as `cmd.exe` and it opens fine. :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

1. Install WSL subsystem (sounds like you already have).
2. Open Visual studio code
3. Open a terminal in visual studio code
4. At the C:\\ prompt type "bash" and press enter.

A great answer with more details on integrating WSL with VS code: [How do I use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (WSL) for my VS Code terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450218/how-do-i-use-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-wsl-for-my-vs-code-terminal)

Comment: I'm not asking to change the default. I'm asking how to open a non-default shell.

Comment: can you not run the non-default shell from the command line? eg open a command window and run the shell?

Comment: The whole point is to open it within VS code. I could set the default to cmd and run `bash` but bash is more often used.

Comment: When you the terminal window in vs code (ctrl+`). Call bash prompt in the command window inside vs code?

Comment: Yes, I can set the default terminal to cmd and run `bash` from inside it in VS code, which will open WSL bash, but I use bash more often than cmd, so I want bash to be default.