# Set environment variables in task.json in vscode for WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-tasks

I tried to set environment variables for my Visual Studio Code tasks that will run in my Windows Subsystem Linux. However, it does not seem to work. Here is my tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test env",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo",
            "args": [
                "$test"
            ],
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "test": "test_string"
                }
            }

        },
    ]
}
```

The output is:

```
> Executing task in folder ex12-test: echo $test <



Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Note that by default shell has been manually modified to `C:\WINDOWS\SysNative\bash.exe`for WSL, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450218/how-do-i-use-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-wsl-for-my-vs-code-terminal) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Debugger/gdb/Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux.md).

Comment: See [environment variable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963423/vscode-environment-variable-in-task-not-found) In your case you need to use `$env:test`

Comment: @Mark Thank you! I changed to ${env:test} and it still wouldn't work. It seems like the environment variable wasn't set at all.

Comment: @YuxiangWang the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963423/vscode-environment-variable-in-task-not-found/56887403#56887403). You simply cannot reference environment variables set in this manner in the `args` or `command` of your tasks.json task definition.

Answer (score 19):

The options object goes outside of any task, so:

```
format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "options": {
      "env": {
        "test": "test_string"
      }
   }
   "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "test env",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo",
        "args": [
            "$env:test"
        ],
    },
```

And then access the options argsuments like so:

```
$env:test  or    ${env:test}
]
```

Comment: It only worked me if I put `"$test"` instead of `"$env:test"`.

Comment: So it is not possible to set an environment variable for a specific task only?

Comment: @godo it's possible here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks. Seems like you'd need to add an `"options"` object to the specific task

Answer (score 6):

What I eventually did for my VS Code (v1.67.1) is:

- Add my env variables into a `settings.json`
- Use the traditional `%ENV_VAR%` option.

So in the `settings.json`, create this:

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": { // switch to your os, check `Open Workspace Settings` in the Command Pallete then search for `environment`
    "AWS_REGION": "us-east-2", 
    "AWS_ID": "my_id"
  }
}
```

In the `tasks.json`, use the proper ENV variable reference:

`"command": "echo %AWS_REGION%"`

Comment: In tasks.json, worked me only this:

`"command": "echo ${env:AWS_REGION}"` 

It depends on used shell.