# VSCode: Environment variable in task not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to define my own environment variables in the tasks.json in VSCode. Following every link I have found so far, I tried the following:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"type": "shell",
"options": {
    "env": {
        "APP_NAME": "myApp"
    }
},
"problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "cpp",
    "fileLocation": [
        "relative",
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "pattern": {
        "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
        "file": 1,
        "line": 2,
        "column": 3,
        "severity": 4,
        "message": 5
    }
},
"presentation": {
    "echo": true,
    "reveal": "always",
    "focus": false,
    "panel": "dedicated",
    "showReuseMessage": false
},
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build Release",
        "command": "python ./scripts/build_app.py $APP_NAME",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

I need this because we are running our build process via a python script and therefore I need to give it the name of the application I want to build. As I am having also python scripts for testing, executing, debugging and so on, I would prefer to change the app name only once in the tasks.json and not in every task itself.

According to the guidelines this should be possible in the way I did it, but in the powershell console the $APP_NAME variable is not substituted. Also neither in the cmd nor bash shell it seems to work.

I would be very grateful for any help someone could give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables set in tasks.json aren't picked up by `${env:..}` in `tasks.json`, nor will they be substituted when given as arguments to the shell. You can however add custom settings in `settings.json`, and reference those in `tasks.json` using `${config:...}`.

e.g.
`settings.json`:

```
{
    "APP_NAME": "myApp",
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"type": "shell",
"options": {
    "env": {
        "APP_NAME": "${config:APP_NAME}"
    }
},
"problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "cpp",
    "fileLocation": [
        "relative",
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "pattern": {
        "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
        "file": 1,
        "line": 2,
        "column": 3,
        "severity": 4,
        "message": 5
    }
},
"presentation": {
    "echo": true,
    "reveal": "always",
    "focus": false,
    "panel": "dedicated",
    "showReuseMessage": false
},
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build Release",
        "command": "python ./scripts/build_app.py ${config:APP_NAME}",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use`$env:APP_NAME` in your case.  See [referencing environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables).

> **Environment variables**
>
> You can also reference environment variables through `${env:Name}`
>   syntax (for example, `${env:PATH}`).

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": [ "${env:USERNAME}" ]
}
```

> Note: Be sure to match the environment variable name's casing, for
>   example `${env:Path}` on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage is incorrect for 1 specific reason.

Environment variables used in the tasks.json `options` object cannot be referenced in the tasks other attributes, specifically `command` in the OPs case:

> **options**: Override the defaults for cwd (current working directory),
>   env (environment variables), or shell (default shell). Options can be
>   set per task but also globally or per platform. Environment variables
>   configured here can only be referenced from within your task script or
>   process and will not be resolved if they are part of your args,
>   command, or other task attributes.

[See options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks)

Try removing the reference to the first argument in the `./scripts/build_app.py` script as the value for `$APP_NAME`, and instead use `os.environ['APP_NAME']` from within in the `./scripts/build_app.py` script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using powershell, use `%VAR%` instead of `$VAR`.

```
"command": "python ./scripts/build_app.py %APP_NAME%",
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Unfortunatly I already tried this and this doesn't work either (at least in powershell)